# Find the number of times typist must press keys to number all the pages.

Tags: number-theory

[image]

**MyApproach**

For,Ist Page He press $0$,for second page He press $1$.Similarly for 2nd Page He press $2$ times etc.

For 1st pages from $1$-$9$,he press $9$ times.

From $10$-$99$ he must have pressed 90 times *$2$=180$ @Edit

From $100$-$999$ he must have pressed $900$ times *$3$=$2700$ @Edit

From 1000-1500 he must have pressed $501$ times * $4$=$2504$ @e]Edit.

Adding all I get $4893$.

Comment: Do note that when you write down $10$ you must press the keyboard $2$ times, multiply that by the number of pages between $10$ and $99$.

You can do the same approach by noting that you must press the keyboard $3$ times when you want to write down $100$, and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake where there are actually 501 numbers between $1000$ and $1500$ instead of $499$.

Other than that I think you are correct, you just need to add them up.

$9+90\times2+900\times3+501\times4=4893$.